# Скопировать столбец из одной базы в другую?

Tags: mysql

Ребята такой вопрос есть две одинаковые базы данных mysql baza1 и mysql baza2 , мне нужно из baza1 c таблицы board скопировать два столбца и перенести их в baza2 в таблицу board как это сделать ?

Как сохранить на ПК целиком таблицу я знаю а вот так сохранить столбец и перенести в другую базу не понимаю.

Comment: посмотрите в сторону команд select и insert

Comment: `SELECT .. INTO OUTFILE` на источнике и `LOAD DATA INFILE` на приёмнике.

Comment: Ребята можете объяснить более понятно ?

Comment: Можно почитать [ТУТ](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/LOAD_DATA.html)